# InvalidOperationException: Unknown connection string parameter 'SSLMode'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, postgresql, entity-framework, dotconnect

I just got into a Asp.NET web-project and I'm trying to setup the application. When I run the application and call an endpoint on localhost I get the error "InvalidOperationException: Unknown connection string parameter 'SSLMode'".

Here is the full stacktrace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: Unknown connection string parameter 'SSLMode'.]
   Devart.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseConnectionString(Hashtable synonyms) +1761
   Devart.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString, Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useFirstKeyValuePair) +232
   Devart.Data.PostgreSql.f..ctor(String A_0) +70
   Devart.Data.PostgreSql.w.a(String A_0, DbConnectionOptions A_1) +38
   Devart.Common.DbConnectionFactory.a(String A_0, DbConnectionOptions& A_1, DbConnectionBase A_2) +128
   Devart.Common.DbConnectionBase.set_ConnectionString(String value) +97
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Action`2 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +98
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbConnectionDispatcher.SetConnectionString(DbConnection connection, DbConnectionPropertyInterceptionContext`1 interceptionContext) +514
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config) +39
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize() +161
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ProviderName() +16
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DefaultModelCacheKeyFactory.Create(DbContext context) +135
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext() +772
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize() +26
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType) +20
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +69
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetAsyncEnumerator() +21
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.ForEachAsync(IDbAsyncEnumerable`1 source, Action`1 action, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +69
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.ToListAsync(IDbAsyncEnumerable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken) +315
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerableExtensions.ToListAsync(IDbAsyncEnumerable`1 source) +55
   SDS1.Business.Repositories.<GetAllApplicationsByRoleAsync>d__6.MoveNext() in ...\Repositories\ApplicationRepository.cs:75
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +32
   MagWien.SDS1Web.Controllers.<Index>d__6.MoveNext() in ...\Controllers\HomeController.cs:39
   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +32
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +92
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__1(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__11_0() +72
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__2() +396
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.<BeginInvokeAction>b__3() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.<BeginInvokeAction>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +188
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginExecuteCore>b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +52
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c.<BeginProcessRequest>b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +73
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +651
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +220
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +134
```

The project uses a postgres database and dotConnect. The application runs just fine on other colleague's machines, yet on mine it doesn't: We are basically utilizing same kinds of virtual machines. Because of this I don't really want to change anything in the code to make the application run. I have dotConnect installed on my machine. If anybody had a similar problem, I would appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Comment: Do the connection string for PostgreSQL all ready there or you are making changes in that? The exception is clearing saying it's not a property of connection string. https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/docs/Devart.Data.PostgreSql~Devart.Data.PostgreSql.PgSqlConnection~ConnectionString.html

Comment: But it was actually. The problem was, even though i had the license info, devart was not installed on my machine... Closing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, even though i had the license info, devart was not installed on my machine... Closing